# Reading JavaScript Variables in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, base64

I am looking for a way to either read an image src in PHP or read a JavaScript variable in PHP.

The plan:
I have a webcam script in JavaScript that takes an image using the base64 Canvas method, but I need it to update a MySQL record using PHP.

After trying many methods; cookies, submit forms, ajax. I decided that making a post here was the best idea.

Comment: Look up `What is the maximum size allowed for a cookie` please

Comment: So is there any alternative ways?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve] and bring it into the question. Links to external sources is not recommended.

Comment: Yea, look up AJAX

Comment: I tried AJAX, i could not get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(!) Use with caution. This is a proof of concept. In PHP you should never just accept and compute client-side data without checking it for malicious code and sanitizing the input. (!)*

You could send it to PHP using AJAX by putting your base64-source into `formData`.

**Javascript**:

```
// ajax.js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // initialize a new XHR
var formData = new FormData(); // initialize form data
var myFile = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

xhr.open('POST', '/requestHandler.php') // init your request
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
// check if the server was able to compute the XHR
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) { 
        // handle the response
        console.log(xhr.responseText) // log the PHP output
    }
}

// a form data element needs a descriptor/name and a value.
formData.append('myfile', myFile);
xhr.send(formData); // send your xhr to the server
```

**PHP**:

```
// requestHandler.php
<?php
if('$_POST') {
    echo $_POST['myfile']; // this is your image source
}
```

Further information:

- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
- [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)
- [PHP $_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: This looks like the exact thing I am looking for. I'm not too worried about the security side of things, as this is only going to be on an internal web server.

Comment: Glad I could help you then. By the way, you recieved that many downvotes because you didn't provide enough code that the community can improve. Stackoverflow tries to be helpful specifically to people who run into problems that already were solved. The downside of this is that it appears to be rather toxic towards new users. These kind of questions often get downvoted and marked as duplicates for no apparent reasen and without an explanation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, the title of your question is misleading. It reads "PHP - Read img src from id" but you did not mention any ID in your question. I would recommend changing it to "Reading javascript variables in PHP" or something similar

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tom.